# Importing pod Framework with same name as Apple Framework

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts, frameworks, cocoapods

I've been using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) pod since iOS 14 for my app and now I want to migrate to iOS16 Charts that Apple provides. So if the user's device is prior to iOS 16 then the pod's framework should be used otherwise the Apple's one. However, when I try to "import Charts", the one selected is always the one from Pods, in any class or file. They are both named "Charts" and I have no selection over which one. Is there any way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CocoaPods just uses the podspecs of your dependencies to generate the `Pods` Xcode project and for xcode projects `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` build settings govern what the name should be used when trying to import the module built by a target. So you can customize this settings to provide different name to the `Charts` pod or ask the pod developer to change the module name.

Pod authors can provide custom module name without changing the pod name with [`module_name`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#module_name) property.

To customize the module name yourself you can add a [`post_install`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install) hook that provides this custom name:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    next if target.product_name != 'Charts'
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME'] = 'CustomCharts'
    end
    break
  end
end
```

And in your code you can import using this custom name i.e. `import CustomCharts`, to use the CocoPods one.

### For Swift packages

With swift 5.7 you can use [module aliases](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0339-module-aliasing-for-disambiguation.md) to disambiguate modules with same name:

```swift
 targets: [
  .executableTarget(
    name: "App",
    dependencies: [
     .product(name: "Charts", package: "Charts", moduleAliases: ["Charts": "CustomCharts"]), 
   ])
 ]
```

Comment: After adding it and making pod install I have errors messages - "underlying objective-c module "CustomCharts" not found"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create .podspec file for Charts, this file must be located in the same directory as .pod, you can download it from Charts github account or use my. You need to add "s.module_name = "CustomCharts"

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = "Charts"
  s.version = "4.1.0"
  s.module_name = "CustomCharts"
  s.summary = "Charts is a powerful & easy to use chart library for iOS, tvOS and OSX (and Android)"
  s.homepage = "https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts"
  s.license = { :type => "Apache License, Version 2.0", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.authors = "Daniel Cohen Gindi", "Philipp Jahoda"
  s.ios.deployment_target = "12.0"
  s.tvos.deployment_target = "12.0"
  s.osx.deployment_target = "10.13"
  s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git", :tag => "v#{s.version}" }
  s.default_subspec = "Core"
  s.swift_version = '5.7'
  s.cocoapods_version = '>= 1.5.0'
  
  s.subspec "Core" do |ss|
    ss.source_files  = "Source/Charts/**/*.swift"
    ss.dependency 'SwiftAlgorithms', '~> 1.0'
  end
end
```

and add this line to your pod file

```
pod 'Charts', :podspec => 'CustomCharts.podspec'
```

**CustomCharts.podspec** must be equal to the **.podspac file name**

After this you can use **import Chart** and **import CustomCharts** in the same directory